# MS Project: How to set daily actual work for a task using a JavaScript Add-In?

Tags: ms-project

I want to synchronize data for actual work from a web-based application of my company with MS Project. I am currently developing an Add-In with JavaScript in order to achieve this:

[image: example]

The red circle in my screenshot shows the data that I want to set programmatically. However, I have no idea how to achieve this.

I understand that I can get Task GUIDs and then set task fields using the task GUID and the field ID. This way I can save the cumulative actual work, but not per day like in my screenshot.

The API Docs on the MS Office Website are rather hard to read and navigate. Any help would be apprechiated!

Answer (score 1):

Let's first separate the language from the operation.

Operationally, based on your circle, you want to set work for a task to happen on individual days? This is done using timeScaleData, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa206255(v=office.11) . When I did something similar (in VBA), I had to (1) get an array of time scale values, then (2) walk/iterate through that array and set work to those days:

```
set timeScaleValsArry = myTask.Assignments(1).TimeScaleData(startDay, endDay, pjAssignmentTimeScaledWork, daily)
for a = 1 to timeScaleValsArry.Count
    timeScaleValsArry[a].value = hoursToWorkThatDay
next
```

Breaking down the elements above:

`myTask` is the task (of type task) I want to manipulate.

`Assignments` is an array representing each resource assigned to the task; for my purposes, I only ever had 1 resource assigned, hence the index of (1).

`TimeScaleData` is the function that returns the the array starting on the day `startDay` (whatever you want that to be), `endDay`, `pjAssignmentTimeScaledWork` which tells this function what data we want to work with (being work, but there are [alternates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa206255(v=office.11)#pjresourcetimescaleddata) ), and `daily` which is the frequency you want to work with (for instance you can go down to minutes, or up to years).

Then the returned array `timeScaleValsArry` is walked, and inside the loop the daily assignment for each `value` is manipulated. You'd need to customize this part to meet your needs; alternatively, you don't even need to loop if you always had three days: just hard code the array indices.

As far as language, clearly this is do-able in VBA. Doing this in C# as a VSTO addin has very similar syntax. I'd presume for JavaScript (what are you using, ScriptLab?) would also have similar syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, the page you are referencing is part of the MS Project 2013 SDK (I'm on MSP 2016) and has been edited in December 2006 for the last time. It is greeting me with a notification that says "We're no longer updating this content regularly. Check the Microsoft Product Lifecycle for information about how this product, service, technology, or API is supported.". As Microsoft points to Office Add-Ins as "the way to go" I'd like to know IF and HOW I can solve my problem using the Office Add-In platform.